# How to get the coordinates of β12 borophene and χ3 borophene?

Tags: theoretical-chemistry, crystal-structure, software, nanotechnology, boron-family

Can someone tell me how to draw the β12 borophen and χ3 borophene in Materials Studio or any other software? I've just started my project work, and I'm a beginner in this field.

I have searched for the coordinates or a .cif file in the literature, but I could not find any. If anyone can provide me with those, it'll also be helpful for me.

Comment: If the references on Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borophene) don't offer a starting point, nor the ICSD database, what entries on _materials project_ like https://materialsproject.org/materials/mp-160/#similar-structures ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For obtaining optimized geometry, energies, and band structure, the Perdew−Burke−Ernzerhof [[1](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.77.3865)] (PBE) functional in nonlocal corrected generalized gradient approximation [[2](https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.45.13244)] (GGA) was used. The OTFG ultrasoft pseudopotential was employed with a plane-wave basis with a kinetic energy cutoff of 520 eV in Monkhorst−Pack [[3](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.45.566)] k-mesh with a 0.04 Å separation in the two lattice directions for geometry optimization. The adjacent sheets were kept 20 Å away to avoid all possible interactions between two nanosheet layers. Individual atom position and lattice parameters have been simultaneously optimized with the chosen cutoff value for SCF tolerance (5.0 × 10-6 eV/ atom) and forces (0.01 eV/Å) to get the well-converged geometries of nanosheets.

- All the calculations were performed using the Cambridge Ab initio Serial Total Energy Package (CASTEP) [[4](https://doi.org/10.1524/zkri.220.5.567.65075)] program based on the above-mentioned density functional theory.

1. Perdew, J. P.; Burke, K.; Ernzerhof, M., Generalized Gradient Approximation Made Simple. Physical Review Letters 1996, 77 (18), 3865-3868. [10.1103/PhysRevLett.77.3865](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.77.3865)
2. Perdew, J. P.; Wang, Y., Accurate and simple analytic representation of the electron-gas correlation energy. Physical Review B 1992, 45 (23), 13244-13249. [10.1103/PhysRevB.45.13244](https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.45.13244)
3. Ceperley, D. M.; Alder, B. J., Ground State of the Electron Gas by a Stochastic Method. Physical Review Letters 1980, 45 (7), 566-569. [10.1103/PhysRevLett.45.566](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.45.566)
4. Clark, S. J.; Segall, M. D.; Pickard, C. J.; Hasnip, P. J.; Probert, M. I. J.; Refson, K.; Payne, M. C., First-principles methods using CASTEP. Zeitschrift für Kristallographie - Crystalline Materials 2005, 220 (5-6), 567-570. [10.1524/zkri.220.5.567.65075](https://doi.org/10.1524/zkri.220.5.567.65075)

Beta_12.cif file:

```
data_Beta_12_str
_audit_creation_date              2021-09-18
_audit_creation_method            'Materials Studio'
_symmetry_space_group_name_H-M    'PMM2'
_symmetry_Int_Tables_number       25
_symmetry_cell_setting            orthorhombic
loop_
_symmetry_equiv_pos_as_xyz
  x,y,z
  -x,-y,z
  x,-y,z
  -x,y,z
_cell_length_a                    2.5600
_cell_length_b                    20.0000
_cell_length_c                    4.2600
_cell_angle_alpha                 90.0000
_cell_angle_beta                  90.0000
_cell_angle_gamma                 90.0000
loop_
_atom_site_label
_atom_site_type_symbol
_atom_site_fract_x
_atom_site_fract_y
_atom_site_fract_z
_atom_site_U_iso_or_equiv
_atom_site_adp_type
_atom_site_occupancy
B1     B     0.00000   0.00000   0.83833   0.00000  Uiso   1.00
B2     B     0.00000   0.00000   0.50500   0.00000  Uiso   1.00
B3     B     0.00000   0.00000   0.17167   0.00000  Uiso   1.00
B4     B    -0.50000   0.00000   0.68718   0.00000  Uiso   1.00
B5     B    -0.50000   0.00000   0.35385   0.00000  Uiso   1.00
loop_
_geom_bond_atom_site_label_1
_geom_bond_atom_site_label_2
_geom_bond_distance
_geom_bond_site_symmetry_2
_ccdc_geom_bond_type
B1     B2      1.420   .     S
B1     B4      1.433   .     S
B1     B4      1.433   1_655 S
B1     B3      1.420   1_556 S
B2     B3      1.420   .     S
B2     B4      1.497   .     S
B2     B4      1.497   1_655 S
B2     B5      1.433   .     S
B2     B5      1.433   1_655 S
B3     B5      1.497   .     S
B3     B5      1.497   1_655 S
B3     B1      1.420   1_554 S
B4     B1      1.433   1_455 S
B4     B5      1.420   .     S
B4     B2      1.497   1_455 S
B5     B3      1.497   1_455 S
B5     B2      1.433   1_455 S
```

Chi_3.cif file:

```
data_chi_3_str
_audit_creation_date              2021-09-18
_audit_creation_method            'Materials Studio'
_symmetry_space_group_name_H-M    'CMMM'
_symmetry_Int_Tables_number       65
_symmetry_cell_setting            orthorhombic
loop_
_symmetry_equiv_pos_as_xyz
  x,y,z
  -x,-y,z
  -x,y,-z
  x,-y,-z
  -x,-y,-z
  x,y,-z
  x,-y,z
  -x,y,z
  x+1/2,y+1/2,z
  -x+1/2,-y+1/2,z
  -x+1/2,y+1/2,-z
  x+1/2,-y+1/2,-z
  -x+1/2,-y+1/2,-z
  x+1/2,y+1/2,-z
  x+1/2,-y+1/2,z
  -x+1/2,y+1/2,z
_cell_length_a                    6.8829
_cell_length_b                    2.8510
_cell_length_c                    20.0000
_cell_angle_alpha                 90.0000
_cell_angle_beta                  90.0000
_cell_angle_gamma                 90.0000
loop_
_atom_site_label
_atom_site_type_symbol
_atom_site_fract_x
_atom_site_fract_y
_atom_site_fract_z
_atom_site_U_iso_or_equiv
_atom_site_adp_type
_atom_site_occupancy
B1     B     0.30945   0.50000   0.00000   0.00000  Uiso   1.00
B2     B     0.10315   0.50000   0.00000   0.00000  Uiso   1.00
loop_
_geom_bond_atom_site_label_1
_geom_bond_atom_site_label_2
_geom_bond_distance
_geom_bond_site_symmetry_2
_ccdc_geom_bond_type
B1     B2      1.420   .     S
B1     B2      1.547   10_565 S
B1     B2      1.547   10    S
B1     B1      1.644   10_565 S
B1     B1      1.644   10    S
B2     B2      1.420   2_565 S
B2     B1      1.547   10_565 S
B2     B1      1.547   10    S
```

Answer (score 3):

Jiang *et al.* 2018 ([DOI: 10.1016/j.jechem.2018.01.026](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jechem.2018.01.026)) may be relevant literature? Here's a quote:

> These include three allotropes named borophene, beta-12(β12) and chi-3(χ3), which
> have been successfully synthesized by physical methods [26,27].
> [**26**] A. J. Mannix, X. F. Zhou, B. Kiraly, J. D. Wood, D. Alducin, B. D. Myers, X. L. Liu, B. L. Fisher, U. Santiago, J. R. Guest, M. J. Yacaman, A. Ponce, A. R. Oganv, M. C. Hersam, N. P. Guisinger, Science 350 (2015) 1513–1516.
> [**27**] B. J. Feng. J. Zhang, Q. Zhong, W. B. Li, S. Li, H, Li, P. Cheng, S. Meng, L. Chen, K. H. Wu, Nat. Chem. 8 (2016) 563-568.

I also found this one:

Izadi Vishkayi, S., Bagheri Tagani, M. Edge-Dependent Electronic and Magnetic Characteristics of Freestanding β 12-Borophene Nanoribbons. Nano-Micro Lett. 10, 14 (2018). [DOI: 10.1007/s40820-017-0167-z](https://doi.org/10.1007/s40820-017-0167-z)

Perhaps you may find the link to the .cif from all of the above?